# Whats the most elegant way to create a jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I would just like to know whats the best of these 3 approaches, and perhaps why?

1)

```
(function($) {
    var methods = {
        init    : function(options) {
            if( this.length ){
                var settings = {
                    something   : 'fast'
                };
                return this.each(function(){
                    if ( options ) {
                        $.extend( settings, options );
                    }

                    var $el         = $(this),

                    /* some variables */
                        $selector1  = $el.find('container'),
                        count       = $selector1.length,
                        $selector2  = $el.find('pictures');

                    /* do something e.g.*/
                    doSomething1();
                    doSomething2();

                    function doSomething1() {
                        $selector1.css('width' , '300px');
                    };

                    function doSomething2() {
                        $selector2.each(function(i) {
                            //do something
                        });
                    };  
                });
            }
        },
        update  : function() { },
        destroy : function() { }
    };

    $.fn.pluginName = function(method) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.pluginName' );
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

2)

```
(function($) {
    var internal= {
        doSomething1    : function($selector1) {
            $selector1.css('width' , '300px');
        },
        doSomething1    : function($selector2) {
            $selector2.each(function(i) {
                //do something
            });
        }
    };

    var methods = {
        init    : function(options) {
            if( this.length ){
                var settings = {
                    something   : 'fast'
                };
                return this.each(function(){
                    if ( options ) {
                        $.extend( settings, options );
                    }

                    /* 
                    The variables are declared here
                    other methods are declared in the internal obj literal
                    */
                    var $el         = $(this),

                    /* some variables */
                        $selector1  = $el.find('container'),
                        count       = $selector1.length,
                        $selector2  = $el.find('pictures');

                    /* do something e.g.*/
                    internal.doSomething1($selector1);
                    internal.doSomething2($selector2);
                });
            }
        },
        update  : function() { },
        destroy : function() { }
    };

    $.fn.pluginName = function(method) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.pluginName' );
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

3)

```
(function($) {
    /* 
    The variables are declared here
    */
    var $el,
        $selector1,
        count,
        $selector2;

    var internal= {
        doSomething1    : function() {
            $selector1.css('width' , '300px');
        },
        doSomething1    : function() {
            $selector2.each(function(i) {
                //do something
            });
        }
    };

    var methods = {
        init    : function(options) {
            if( this.length ){
                var settings = {
                    something   : 'fast'
                };
                return this.each(function(){
                    if ( options ) {
                        $.extend( settings, options );
                    }

                    /* 
                    The variables are set here
                    other methods are declared in the internal obj literal
                    */
                    $el         = $(this),
                    $selector1  = $el.find('container'),
                    count       = $selector1.length,
                    $selector2  = $el.find('pictures');

                    /* do something e.g.*/
                    internal.doSomething1();
                    internal.doSomething2();
                });
            }
        },
        update  : function() { },
        destroy : function() { }
    };

    $.fn.pluginName = function(method) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.pluginName' );
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2) is the correct answers.

For 1) there is no reason to create a new instance of the two functions for each `.pluginName` call since they are static.

For 3) I consider it bad practice to make those local `.pluginName` call specific variables static to your plugin. It may not cause an error right now but it's likely to induce subtle bugs.

Basically everything inside the `init` function should be specific to the call where as everything inside your `(function($) {` closure should be static to your plugin.

Have you tried 4) ?

```
(function($) {
    var MyObject = function($el) {
        /* 
        The variables are declared here
        other methods are declared in the internal obj literal
        */
        /* some variables */
        this.$selector1  = $el.find('container');
        var count       = $selector1.length;
        this.$selector2  = $el.find('pictures');

        /* do something e.g.*/
        this.doSomething1($selector1);
        this.doSomething2($selector2);
    };

    MyObject.prototype.doSomething1 = function() {
       this.$selector1.css('width' , '300px');
    };
    MyObject.prototype.doSomething2 = function() {
       this.$selector2.each(function(i) {
           //do something
       });
    };

    var methods = {
        init    : function(options) {
            if( this.length ){
                var settings = {
                    something   : 'fast'
                };
                return this.each(function(){
                    if ( options ) {
                        $.extend( settings, options );
                    }

                    new MyObject($(this));
                });
            }
        },
        update  : function() { },
        destroy : function() { }
    };

    $.fn.pluginName = function(method) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.pluginName' );
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

As a general comment having an API of `$(obj).pluginName("method", ...)` can be annoying/unintuitive as an API design.

I would recommend allow you to `$(obj).pluginName().method(...)` aswell to keep the jQuery chaining thing going.

Comment: My preference and the one I am currently using is also (2). However, I have a plugin with a lot of variables, which I will need to pass to my functions. This can get really annoying e.g. internal.doSomething1(var1,var2,var3,var4);

Comment: Note that on (2) I forgot to pass the variables in the function calls :S it should have been internal.doSomething1($selector1); internal.doSomething2($selector2);

Comment: In that case your doSomething(...) should take a settings object instead

Comment: @Ricardo Why don't you pass $el to the function and let the function get the selectors / other variables etc.

Comment: because if all my functions, or some of them need to work with $el.find('.someclass'), then I would think I would be doing unnecessary selectors, right?

Comment: Maybe I explained it wrong: I mean I would be getting $el.find('.someclass') "n" times, when I could do it just once

Comment: @Ricardo yes that would be bad. have you considered having an object to do this for? See edit to answer.